# Testing whether a tetrahedron lies inside a Polyhedron

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, topology

I have a [tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) $t$ and a [polyhedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron) $p$. $t$ is constrained such that it always shares all its vertices with $p$. I want to determine whether $t$ lies *inside* $p$.

I would like to add one detail to the problem in case it may contribute to the solution: $t$ is a *Delaunay* tetrahedron and faces of $p$ are triangular and are *strongly Delaunay* both with respect to vertices of $p$. A tetrahedron is *Delaunay* if [circumsphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_sphere) of its vertices contains no other vertex inside it. A face is *strongly Delaunay* if there exists a circumsphere containing vertices of that face on its surface but no other vertex *on* or *inside* it.

Following figures show the same problem in $2D$ space:

**The original polygon $p$**:

[image]

**Delaunay triangulation of vertices of $p$**:

[image]

**Result of *inside/outside* test over triangles $t$**(Shaded triangles are *inside* $p$ and rest are *outside*):

[image]

**Desired result(pruning *outside* triangles)**:

[image]

---

My original problem is in 3D space so triangles $t$ in above figures translate to tetrahedrons and polygon $p$ translates to an *arbitrary* polyhedron $p$. I have figured out some formulations of this problem:

**Formulation 1**
The only parts of $t$ which can be outside $p$ are its edges and triangular faces but in general there may exist a $p$ which has edges of all *outside* $t$'s on its surface, so alternatively, this problem may also be formulated as to test whether for a tetrahedron $t$ there exists a face which lies *outside* $p$?

**Formulation 2**
I have another possible perspective towards this problem but lacking any formal idea:
Geometrically, if $t$ is outside then it will always be *sticking* on the *outer* surface of $p$. So if we can compute the *contours*(informally, the outer boundary)  $C_{V}$ and $C_{V_{p}}$ such that $V=V_{t}\cup V_{p}$ and $V_t,V_p$ are sets of vertices in $t,p$ respectively, then $C_{V}=C_{V_p}$ *iff* $t$ lies inside $p$.

I would like to know:

- How can I solve either of **Formulation 1** or **Formulation 2**?
- Or, is there any completely different approach to solve this?

**Update:**
I now realize that this problem can be reduced to *Point in polyhedron* problem. Since an *outside* tetrahedron $t$ will have *at least* one face which lies outside $p$, so any arbitrary point on that face(except its vertices,in general) will always lie *outside* $p$. Therefore, for each face of $t$, I need to take an arbitrary point and test if that point lies *outside* $p$.

From [point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) article I came to know about **Ray casting algorithm** and **Winding number algorithm**. Ray casting is not *numerically stable* for cases where point lies on the surface of $p$. But numerical robustness of Winding number algorithm has not been addressed there.

Based on above, my core problem now seems to be(please suggest if it should be asked as a separate question):
Is there any numerically robust algorithm for *point in polygon* problem?

Comment: Just to clarify: 1) Can the polyhedron $p$ be non-convex, and 2) if $t$ and $p$ share a face or an edge (or part of one), does that disqualify $t$ from being "inside" of $p$? (Obviously, based on your requirements, $t$ and $p$ must be allowed to share vertices.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen 1) Yes 2). No, as far as I can imagine, the only difference between _inside_ and _outside_ tetrahedron will be that its non-shared face/edge will lie _outside_ if $t$ is outside $p$ and _inside_ if $t$ is inside $p$(as I have also mentioned under **Formulation 1**). BTW, what do you mean by "...or part of one..."?

Comment: Two coplanar faces or collinear edges might overlap only partially. This could happen even if $p$ itself has no coincident faces or edges, as long as it has more than two collinear or more than three coplanar vertices.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I now realized that if $p$ is convex then there can be no tetrahedron $t$ outside it. So now I need to test $t$ against non-convex polyhedrons $p$ only.

Comment: non-convexity has the oddity that all vertices can be *inside* the polyhedron and yet the tetrahedron can be *outside* (since an edge need not lie inside as a whole). Possible algorithm, see if edges (between polyhedron and tetrahedron) can have intersections => prob that tetrahedron lies outside is great

Comment: Have you seen the Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi distance algorithm? You would need to decompose the polygon/polyhedron into convex shapes first (as you noted, a simplicial complex would do the job). GJK is known to be very stable and very fast.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found one solution to this problem in a paper 'Robust inside-outside segmentation using generalized winding numbers' by Alec Jacobson et.al., [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2461916). It solves the problem of locating if a point is inside(or outside) an arbitrary(one with self-intersections, non-manifold, open-surfaces etc.) polygonal mesh using the notion of *generalized winding number*.

Problem can be solved if I compute the generalized winding number of the centroid of $t$ against the surface of $p$.

Comment: Point containment will not solve the problem: Picture $p$ a [triangular prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism) with one side of ("Platonic") $t$ (slightly smaller, inside,) parallel and near to one of the triangular faces of $p$. Now subtract from $p$ a "needle tetrahedron" from the middle of that face to near one of the vertices "in the opposite face": None of $t$'s vertices is outside $p$, none of $p$'s vertices is inside $t$, yet $t$ is not inside $p$.